# Why, in a classification task, with $n$ input variables, we can obtain all $2^n$ classiﬁcation functions for each possible set of missing inputs?

Tags: classification

I don't get why, for a classification task with missing values, **With $n$ input variables, we can obtain all $2^n$ diﬀerent classiﬁcation functions needed for each possible set of missing inputs,**.

> *Classiﬁcation becomes more challenging if the computer program is not
> guaranteed that every measurement inits input vector will always be
> provided. To solve the classiﬁcation task, thelearning algorithm only
> has to deﬁne a single function mapping from a vectorinput to a
> categorical output. When some of the inputs may be missing,rather than
> providing a single classiﬁcation function, the learning algorithm ˜must
> learn a set of functions. Each function corresponds to
> classifying with diﬀerent subset of its inputs missing. This kind of
> situation arises frequently in medical diagnosis because many kinds of
> medical tests are expensive or invasive. One way to eﬃciently deﬁne
> such a large set of functions is to learn a probability distribution
> over all the relevant variables, then solve the theclassiﬁcation task by
> marginalizing out the missing variables. **With $n$ input variables, we can now obtain all $2^n$ diﬀerent classiﬁcation functions needed for each possible set of missing inputs,** but the computer program needs to learn only a single function describing the joint probability distribution for an example of a deep probabilistic model applied to such a task in this way.* - Goodfelloz et al., [*Deep Learning*, chapter 5](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html)

Indded, I get that each variable offers either Classification A/Classification B output, and that we have n variables so that we have $\overbrace{2\times 2\times ... \times 2}^{n \ times}$ possible outpus. But that doesn't make functions, does it?

I am a slow learner, don't hesitate to explain it to me with dummy examples or graphs :)